Keep the order of rows of column of merged data frame the same as the rows of the common column of the 2 initial dataframes
I have 2 dataframes which I merge based ona a common column. What I want is the order of the rows of the new dataframe to be first the order of alltr Attribute Name and then the one of allev.Not in alphabetical order and not having to set the order manually after merging. So the order of the Attribute Name column in the new one should be Age, Gender, Income, Area
# Sample dataframes
alltr <- data.frame(
  `Attribute Name` = c("Age", "Gender"),
  Value_x = c(254, 100)
)

allev <- data.frame(
  `Attribute Name` = c("Income", "Area"),
  Value_y = c(708, 500)
)

# Merging the dataframes
merged_df2 <- merge(alltr, allev, by = "Attribute Name", all = TRUE)


merge() has a sort argument, so you can do:
merge(alltr, allev, by = "Attribute.Name", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)

  Attribute.Name Value_x Value_y
1            Age     254      NA
2         Gender     100      NA
3         Income      NA     708
4           Area      NA     500

Alternatively, you can use dplyr::full_join():
dplyr::full_join(alltr, allev, by = "Attribute.Name")

  Attribute.Name Value_x Value_y
1            Age     254      NA
2         Gender     100      NA
3         Income      NA     708
4           Area      NA     500


by = "Attribute.Name" isn't really necessary in merge.
